# SQL VIEWS/ data type conversion

Tags: sql-server

I am trying to crate a view. one of the fields in the view is a smalldatetime character type. I am trying to display records within a certain date range. There seems to be a character type conversion issue. the error i am getting is *"The conversion of a varchar data type to a smalldatetime data type resulted in an out-of-range value."*

Here is my piece of code

```
CREATE VIEW erep
AS
SELECT [iInvoiceID] as invoice_id
      ,[OrderDate] as rrdate
      ,[cDescription] as product
      ,[fQtyProcessed] as qty
      ,[fUnitPriceExcl] as unitpricenotax
      ,[fUnitPriceIncl] as unitpricewithtax
      ,[fUnitCost] as unitcost
      ,[fTaxRate] as taxrate
      ,[fQuantityLineTotIncl] as totalwithtax
      ,[fQuantityLineTotExcl] as totalnotax
      ,[fQuantityLineTotInclNoDisc] as totalwithtaxnodiscount
      ,[fQuantityLineTotExclNoDisc] as totalnotaxnodisc
      ,[iDeliveryStatus] as deliverystatus
        FROM _bvSalesOrdersFull
  where orderdate >= '2017-01-01 00:00:00' AND orderdate < '2017-31-12 00:00:00';
```

Comment: its likely a timezone issue. Is it giving for orderdate column ?

Answer (score 0):

For your datetime literals, use a format that is unambiguous, no matter what the language/culture settings are:

```
CREATE VIEW erep
AS
SELECT [iInvoiceID] as invoice_id
      ,[OrderDate] as rrdate
      ,[cDescription] as product
      ,[fQtyProcessed] as qty
      ,[fUnitPriceExcl] as unitpricenotax
      ,[fUnitPriceIncl] as unitpricewithtax
      ,[fUnitCost] as unitcost
      ,[fTaxRate] as taxrate
      ,[fQuantityLineTotIncl] as totalwithtax
      ,[fQuantityLineTotExcl] as totalnotax
      ,[fQuantityLineTotInclNoDisc] as totalwithtaxnodiscount
      ,[fQuantityLineTotExclNoDisc] as totalnotaxnodisc
      ,[iDeliveryStatus] as deliverystatus
        FROM _bvSalesOrdersFull
  where orderdate >= '2017-01-01T00:00:00' AND orderdate < '2017-12-31T00:00:00';
```

But not that I would *expect* the end point to be `'2018-01-01T00:00:00'` unless its your intention to exclude orders that occur *during* the last day of December.

Unambiguous date formats are `YYYYMMDD`, `YYYY-MM-DD'T'hh:mm:ss` and `YYYY-MM-DD'T'hh:mm:ss.mil`. Some other formats *may* work well these days but historically SQL Server could get confused with them; notably `YYYY-MM-DD` used to have issues, I believe. As does using a space as the date/time separator.